# How to use Luxon as createdAt and updatedAt colmun in TypeOrm Entity

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm building something in NestJS. Whenever possible I want to **stay away from that dangerous `Date` object of JS**. So I'm using Luxon.
How do I use Luxon as `createdAt` and `updatedAt` column with default value to current time.

Following is the Entity

```js
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import { User } from '../users/user.entity';

export enum FeedType {
  Image = 'image',
  Video = 'video',
  Text = 'text',
}

@Entity()
export class Feed {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  title: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  body: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  attachment: string;

  @Column()
  type: FeedType;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdAt: DateTime;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt: DateTime;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.feeds)
  user: User;
}
```

Migrations generated from this entity fails with following msg

```js
{
code: 'ER_INVALID_DEFAULT',
  errno: 1067,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "Invalid default value for 'createdAt'",
  sql: "CREATE TABLE `feed` (`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `title` varchar(255) NULL, `body` varchar(255) NULL, `attachment` varchar(255) NULL, `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `createdAt` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NOW()', `updatedAt` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NOW()' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), `userId` int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB"
}
```

I've also used `NOW()` as default instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but the outcome is same.